# Angular directive not getting called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular and trying to run this code on creating a wordcloud and my directive is not getting called. Am I missing something?

```
angular.module('pivot.directives', ['charts.wordcloud'])

.directive('cloud', function (wordcloud) {
    console.log("here");
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: { words: "=words", live: "=live", interval: "=interval", callback: "=callback" },
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            function init() {
                elem.empty();
                $scope.wordCloud = wordcloud.WordCloud(elem.width(), elem.width() * 0.75, 250, $scope.callback, elem);
            }
            init();

            /** re-initialize wordCloud on window resize */
            $(window).resize(function () { _.throttle(init, 1000)(); });
        }
    }
});
```

And my HTML

```
<div id="wordCloud" class="cloud" data-words="words" data-live="live" data-interval="200"
                            data-callback="addSearchString">
                        </div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing at all, Thats what I found weird. Either I missed something really big. I have added directives in app.js file as well.

Comment: The `pivot.directives` is included in the module that is used in `ng-app` or when manually bootstrapping?

Comment: included in module that is used in ng-app

Comment: Version of AngularJS?

Comment: Now added this simple directive, even this is not working

 .directive('setFirstActive', function() {
        console.log("here");
      return function(scope, element, attrs){
          alert('sample');
          element.addClass("active");     
      };
  });

<div class="item" ng-repeat="viewPrintcampaign in viewPrintcampaigns" ng-init="first=$first" setFirstActive> 
        </div>

Comment: Sorry guys, this was my mistake

Solved this by adding 'pivot.directives'in my controller.js module. Working now

Thanks for your help. Cheers.